# Как сделать редирект htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Есть страница типа **site.com/news/?page=2**

Нужно сделать вот так **site.com/news/page/2**

Comment: `RewriteRule ^news/page/(\d+)$ /news?page=$1`

Comment: вообще-то адрес вот-такой) со слешем)
news/?page=2, но не работает чет

Comment: а что на входе и в куда преобразуем?  сейчас  news/page/(\d+) => /news?page=$1  Или хотим наоборот?

Comment: поправил сообщение

Comment: RewriteRule ^news/page/(\d+)$ /news/?page=$1

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^news/$ /news/page/%1
```

Comment: в директиве news, вставил Ваш код, не работает

Comment: Я у себя на тестовом сайте сделал этот htaccess ввожу `test1.ru/http:/news/?page=34` получаю  `/news/page/34`

Comment: неа, не работает, ладно буду искать на форумах ответ

Comment: Странно, однако :(  А что-то  еще в htaccess написано?

Comment: нет, только код что выше

Comment: А как не работает? пишет, что не не найдено `/news/?page=34`? что-то происходит?

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /news/page/2 was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Тогда я ничего не понимаю. что вводится в адресную строку? /news/page/2 ? тогда поставь, наоборот, вот это `RewriteRule ^news/page/(\d+)$ /news?page=$1` вместо двух последних строк

Comment: да, именно так ввожу, и нет, не получается(

Comment: Вот сейчас у меня написано `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news/page/(\d+)$ /new?page=$1`  задаю  `/news/?page=34` вызывается с `GET["page"] 34`

Comment: задаю news/?page=2 работает, задаю news/page/2 вручную не работает

Comment: А в таком стиле как это прописать?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !page=
RewriteRule page/(.*)$ /?page=$1

Comment: Это означать - если нет query page=,то выполнить след. Рул . Если так, то все верно, но логика странная

Comment: так как прописать такой код для news/?page=2

Comment: Открываешь http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ вводишь  урл `http://example.com/news/?page=2`  пишешь `RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^news/page/(\d+)$ /news/?page=$1`  нажимаешь `Check now` смотришь внизу справа, что получилось

Comment: output url - http://example.com/news/?page=2

Comment: а что хотелось бы?

Comment: example.com/news/page/2

Comment: а стоп, тут то работает, а у меня не хочет

Comment: и у меня работает. Может, mod Rewrite не подключен?

Comment: так ведь этот код на главной странице то работает
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !page=
RewriteRule page/(.*)$ /?page=$1

Comment: первую строчку можно выбросить, она не нужна

Comment: спасибо за помощь в общем)